# Increasing Speed in While Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a bot to play FNF. Obviously this means I need a bot that's fast, but my code runs really slow. I know this is because the processes I'm doing are quite heavy, but I don't know how to speed it up.

EDIT: I've updated my code but it's still nowhere near fast enough

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import PIL.ImageGrab
import time

keyPresser = Controller()

while True:

    pic = PIL.ImageGrab.grab((2000, 400, 2001, 401))
    pic2 = pic.convert("RGB") 
    rgbPixelValue = pic2.getpixel((0, 0))
    if rgbPixelValue != (134, 163, 173):
        keyPresser.press(Key.left)
    
    print(rgbPixelValue)
```

Comment: Could it help to run several threads doing the Same stuff? Or has it to be done one after another? And as I See in your snippet, the object `pic` never changes, right?

Comment: One problem is that you're grabbing **the entire screen** (most likely more than 1000000 pixels) just to read one single pixel. If you look at the definition of `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` you'll see it takes an optional bounding box. Supplying one would definitely help.

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky It needs to take a picture every game frame to tell when the markers are over the arrows in the game